# Is it not necessary to add instructions to install CUDA / TensorRT packages for Docker images deployed on AWS ECR and to be used on Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, inference, tensorrt, onnxruntime

Recently I have been learning to deploy Onnx models for inference on AWS sagemaker, specifically using the onnxruntime library. And one of steps is being to deploy a Docker image of my model (which includes an inference.py script that defines how to load a model instance and how to do predictions) on AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR). And it is how my infernce.py script looks like:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from onnxruntime import InferenceSession
import onnxruntime as ort

providers = ['TensorrtExecutionProvider'] # 'CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider'

def load_model(model_dir: str) -> InferenceSession:
    """
    Load the model from the specified directory.
    """
    return InferenceSession(
        os.path.join(model_dir, 
        "onnx_model/gpt2-lm-head-10.infer.onnx"),
        providers=providers)

def predict(body: dict, model: InferenceSession) -> dict:
    """
    Generate predictions for the incoming request using the model.
    """
    features = np.array(body["features"])
    ort_inputs = dict(
        {model.get_inputs()[0].name : features}
    )

    res = model.run(None, ort_inputs)

    ans = res[0]

    return {"predictions": ans.tolist(),"device": ort.get_device(),"providers": providers}
```

And this is how my docker file looks like:

```
FROM python:3.10.4

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

# build docker image: --no-cache-dir can save storage space
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV SM_MODEL_DIR /opt/ml/model

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "app:app", "-n"]
```

As far as I know, using the base Docker image 'python:3.10.4' doesn't mean the environment has CUDA / TensorRT packages installed and the user needs to specifiy some 'apt-get install xxx' operations to make it work. But to my surprise, even when I set the **providers** in the inference.py to ['TensorrtExecutionProvider'], ['CUDAExecutionProvider'] or ['CPUExecutionProvider'], my AWS sagemaker can work perfectly (i.e. the returned 'device' and 'providers' attributes are correct) when I deploy it using ml.g4dn.xlarge on AWS. Can I be reassured that AWS has done the work behind (e.g. installing the neccessary packages to run inference using CUDA and even TensorRT) so that I do not need to worry about this?